How to calculate stripline asymmetric impedance on Saturn PCB toolkit?
I am designing a PCB layout. This PCB contains 75 ohm video traces. Also, these traces only give output from the connector to another connector. When I make a calculation in the stripline asymmetric section with Saturn PCB, "Default", "IPC-2141" and "wadell" options appear. I have a stack up structure as in the photo and there is a difference of 2 times between the default and the other two options. This difference occurs with the H2 measurement. Which one should I base my calculation on?



Are you sure your situation is within the range of validity for the approximations made by each method? Your signal conductor is very far from the center, much more so than usual for asymmetric stripline. This means it has to be very narrow to reach the desired impedance, which means poor impedance control. Consider making some changes to your stackup, or changing to a different type of waveguide.

I tried two field solvers on this configuration. They both agree fairly closely. If the default Saturn solver is showing 38.7 ohms (the value is obliterated by the red line!), then the default solver is doing a better job than the IPC-2141 solver.
ATLC (Arbitrary Transmission Line Calculator).
The top image is the input file which depicts the conductors and dielectric. Green is  ground, red is the conductor, grey is the dielectric.Due to highly unsymmetrical placement of the conductor, there is fringing issues which will affect the impedance.

The output showing the E-field (image gamma was changed to better show the field distribution):

Text output from the program:
Er=  4.30 Zo =  43.83 Ohms C =  157.8 pF/m L =  303.2 nH/m v = 1.446e+008 m/s
Polar impedance solver.
I asked a colleague who has access to the Polar solver to run your configuration. I used a rectangular cross section for the conductor.
Results:
Zo = 42.37 ohms
C = 163 pF/m
For a surface microstrip: Zo = 50 ohms
For a embedded microstrip: Zo = 42.64 ohms
You can see that the bottom plane has little effect on the impedance when comparing against an embedded microstrip.

so, i found a solve and share with you. I made a stackup setting again. I obtained 65 ohm impedance in this configuration. I think this impedance value may be sufficient for analog video lines such as rs343/rs170. What do you think?


Waddell's Book explains why the results are different and the formulae are rather complex. Basically, it has to do with "incremental capacitance, Ci" models, which are different for symmetry, asymmetric and insanely asymmetric, as posed in this question. When the dielectric thickness of your dielectric gap is less than 70% of the track width, the Ci becomes more sensitive than the Li, and so the Zo drops more.
So the default formula is more accurate.
All the research is based on a bunch of names I would never remember like Rao, Das, Robrish, Cohn, Howe, Hogan and of course ;) Wheeler who mastered the complex inductance side and naturally, Brian Wadell and his book transmission-line-design-handbook-brian-c-wadell_compress.pdf which you may find on the web.
But I say, why bother with such expense for 6 MHz Video signals. A 1 ns delay is not going to impact your s11 or your s21 loss or chroma discoloration (Chroma carrier quadrature phase shift).
But if you insist... let me show you an easier way using dual coplanar edge microstrip.

Thank you so much, I will use this pcb for test. I will generate an image from a generator, pass it through this card and check the image on the monitor. I wanted it to be a 4-layer PCB. I am open to all your suggestions.

so, i found a solve and share with you. I made a stackup setting again. I obtained 65 ohm impedance in this configuration. I think this impedance value may be sufficient for analog video lines such as rs343/rs170. What do you think?

I think a 2 layer is adequate and Zo=200 or anything would have no difference because Td= 1ns and group delay or phase error is not sensitive to that is just < 1% of a pixel.  Notice all VGA cables have huge ferrite clamps for Vcm noise. This is more important. the difference in ground noise.

Coplanar wave puts gnd on either side and under the trace with gnd plane. So top traces are g R g G g B g,  so g=gnd and use 10 mil track/gap =cheap  !!
